# Spring Boot mail error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

The following error shows in Eclipse

> Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;

---

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

app properties:

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username =test@example.com
spring.mail.password =**********************
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
support.email=test@example.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

I have tried everything: deactivated antivirus, enabled less secure changing port to 465 or 25 without result.

Comment: Have you enabled SMTP access in your Gmail account? I don't believe that it's switched on by default.

Comment: yes its enabled

Comment: Have you enabled ssl?
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true

Comment: okey its working after deleting some properties and desactivating avast for 10 minutes , but now how can i make it running withotu disabling avast

Comment: If avast is providing a firewall, you need to configure it to allow connections to that port on that host.  Also, get rid of all that socket factory stuff, [you don't need it](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to desactivate avast before runing the application, but now how can i make it running without disabling avast regulary.